# Jquery and AJAX script to run a PHP script in the background to avoid any refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have built a follow/unfollow Twitter like system using PHP. Now I would like to run the follow-unfollow PHP script in the background using AJAX/JQUERY to avoid refreshing the page when you follow/unfollow a user. To make things simpler, I will be here just using the example of “unfollow”. As you notice, I am running an iteration to output all the members in the database. I am outputting here (as well for simplicity) just the member’s name and an unfollow button to each one.

This is the code using php.

*members.php*

```
<?php  foreach($members as $member){ ?>
 <p class="member_name"><?php echo $member->name; ?></p>
<a href="follow_actions.php?unfollow_id=<?php echo $member->id; ?>"><p class="follow_button">Unfollow</p></a> 
<?php } ?>
```

*unfollow.php*

```
    <?php
    if($_GET['unfollow_id']){
    $unfollow_id=$_GET['unfollow_id'];
    $unfollow=Following::unfollow($id, $unfollow_id); //Function that will make the changes in the database.
                                                    // $id argument will be gotten from a $_SESSION.

}
```

I am trying to achieve the same result running unfollow.php in the background to avoid any refreshing. This is what I have come up with, as you might imagine it is not working properly. I am including the Jquery script inside the iteration which I think is the only way of obtaining the `$member->id` property to then assign it to the Jquery variable.

*members.php THE NEW ONE THAT TRYS TO RUN THE SCRIPT WITH AJAX JQUERY*

```
<?php  foreach($members as $member){ ?>
     <p class="member_name"><?php echo $member_name; ?></p>
     <button  type="button" class="unfollow_button" id="unfollow">Unfollow</button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#unfollow").click(function(){
                // Get value from input element on the page
                var memberId = "<?php $member->id ?>";

                // Send the input data to the server using get
                $.get("unfollow.php", {unfollow_id: memberId} , function(data){
                    // Success

                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
        <?php } ?>
```

Can you provide me any help for this to work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're missing an echo here : var memberId = "<?php $member->id ?>";

Comment: and that assumes the `memberID` is static, if you want to actually grab the value of an input element on the page, you're going to have to get it with javascript, PHP can't touch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, in HTML, id attributes have to be unique.

Because you're rendering multiple members on a single page, you should not use an id selector in jQuery, but a class selector (e.g. `button.unfollow`).  If you use `#unfollow`, you'll run into ID conflicts between each of the members' buttons.

First, render all of your members with unfollow buttons without ids.  I'm adding the member_id in the markup using a data attribute called `data-member_id`.

```
<?php  foreach($members as $member) { ?>
    <p class="member_name"><?=$member_name?></p>
    <button type="button" class="unfollow_button" data-member_id="<?=$member->id?>">Unfollow</button>
<?php } ?>
```

Then add a single click handler for all `button.follow` buttons, which extracts the `member_id` from the clicked button's `data-member_id` attribute and sends it to the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button.unfollow_button").on('click', function() {
        // Get value from input element on the page
        var memberId = $(this).attr('data-member_id');
        // Send the input data to the server using get
        $.get("unfollow.php", {unfollow_id: memberId} , function(data) {
            // Success
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

On a side-note, you should probably look into building a RESTful service for this, to which you can post proper HTTP requests using http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

See here for an intro on REST in PHP I wrote a while back:

[Create a RESTful API in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662638/create-a-restful-api-in-php)

Comment: Thanks so much @StevenMoseley for you reply. I have updated my code with you suggestions but it isn't working. What is the best way to share here my current code? Do I have to use just the comments. I can't seem to format properly the code blocks in the comments. I just have to indent four spaces and wrap my code in <code> tags right? Not working for me...

Comment: Do I have to put something in after function(data){        } I have no code there.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the jquery script. I am putting the values of the variables manually to discard any problems of getting the values dinamically throug PHP, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @ArthurCastus - You have to change it to use `button.unfollow_button` in the jQuery script.  I had incorrectly specified `button.unfollow`

Comment: @ArthurCastus - Here's a jsFiddle showing it working with the proper class name: http://jsfiddle.net/tnkm03cc/ (you can see it logging to the console)

Comment: It is working now. What was happening is that the <button> was nested inside a php if statement, that was the way I was changing dinamically the buttons to "follow or unfollow"  with the php system. I didn't know that interfered with the Jquery/Ajax call, that was why I wasn´t getting any response. I gues the way now to change dinamically the buttons will have to be only through Jquery itself. I will be working on this and perhaps I will post another question on that LOL. Thank you Steven so much for taking the time to help me. It is greatly appreciated!!!